# why do we need strcpy()?

Tags: c++, c

```
struct prac
{
    int name[3];
    char name1[12];
} b1, b2, c2;

main()
{
    int i;
    struct prac b2={1,2,3};

    strcpy(c2.name1,"goodmorning");

    printf("%s",c2.name1);
}
```

here to store the values in b2 array we just need to write b2={1,2,3} but if I want to store some values in the string c2 we need to call strcpy(), why it shows error if I write c2="goodmorning", rather than using strcpy()?

Comment: **–1** Please only post **code that compiles** with at least one standard-conforming compiler.

Comment: Note that you can indeed initialise a string in the same way that `b2` is initialised: `char name[] = "goodmorning";`

Comment: You could write: `struct prac d0 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, "this works!" };` quite happily.

Comment: choose one: c or c++. Your code wasn't compilable in C++ because no default types allowed. Plus those two languages  are quite different inside, especially in case of initializing

Answer (score 8):

Because you can't ***assign*** to an array, only ***initialize*** it (which you do when you define the *second* `b2` variable) or by ***copying*** to it (which you do with the `strcpy` call).

Comment: struct prac
    {
        int name[3];
        char name1[12];
    } b1, b2, c2;
    
    main()
    {
        int i;
     struct prac b2={1,2,3};
     
     strcpy(c2.name1,"goodmorning");
     
     printf("%s",c2.name1);
    }
here to store the values in 'b2' array we just need to write 'b2={1,2,3}' but if I want to store some values in the string 'c2' we need to call 'strcpy()', why it shows error if I write 'c2="goodmorning"'?

Comment: @SampadSaha When you do e.g. `struct prac bc = { ... }` you are *initializing* the structure. When you do `c2.name1 = "..."` you attempt to *assign* to an array. The `=` operator means different things in different contexts. Initialization is okay, assignment is not.